# copy paste using Recursion

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA coding

I am trying to write a code to copy data from on sheet to another by searching  and for that I am using recursion 
And the code looks something like this

```
Sub macro()
While s <> ""
Here comes copying each line and moving to the other page and searching for which row to post it on
After pasting 
Call macro and then there is 
end if
And wend
End sub
```

My issue here is when it comes to the call macro it starts from the first and then check for while condition and when the while condition is not met it should come out end the sub but it doesn't after end sub its again going back to end if.can someone help me with this

**EDIT**

```
Sub macro() 
dim issue as string 
dim i as integer 
  sheets(age).activate 
  while s <> "value" 
    activecell.offset(1,0) 
    Issue = active cell.value
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy 
    sheets(age1).activate 
    range(A1).select 
    for I =1 to 12 
      if active cell = issue activecell.offset(0,1) Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False    
        call macro 
      end if 
    Next i
  wend 
end sub
```

Comment: Probably because that isn't actual code.  Paste your real code so some one can try to help.

Comment: Sub macro() dim issue as string dim i as integer  sheets(age).activate while s <> "value" activecell.offset(1,0)  ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy sheets(age1).activate range(A1).select for I =1 to 12 if active cell = issue activecell.offset(0,1) Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False  call macro  end if  wend end sub.  Where value is the end of the data

Comment: I added the code to the post, it shouldn't be in the comments, too hard to read.  There is no way that code even compiles...you are missing "then" and "next I".  Also the activecell thing could be part of your issue, try starting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: The code looks incomplete even after the edit

Comment: Hi ya sorry I don't have the code right now so typed it again ya it does have then for if statement and next I for "for" statement and after while part there is a code line issue = active cell.value

Comment: You never set the value of `s` which is used as the condition of your `WHILE` loop. If `s` never changes, then your While loop will just keep looping. That, and this code would never run as it's riddled with mistakes. Why don't you wait until you have your actual code to ask the question?